# Set last N values of dataframe to NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to group my dataframe and set the last N values of a column in each group to NA. I can do it for N = 1 like so:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(target = c(target[-n()], NA))
```

But am struggling to get it to work for any N

This is my current attempt:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(target = c(target[1:(abs(n()-1))], NA))
```

But this seems to fail for groups of size 1

I also tried:

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(target = ifelse(n()==1, target, c(target[1:(abs(n()-1))], NA)))
```

But the else clause never takes effect.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Question: what should happen if there are fewer than `N` rows in a group?  Should they _all_ be set to `NA`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(target = replace(target, tail(row_number(), N), NA))
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make the value default to target when the group size == 1?

Comment: @Jage Not clear what you meant.  Did you meant to return the same row when group size is 1.  `tail` does that automatically

Comment: Currently, if a group size is 1, it will set target to NA. I was able to do it by doing mutate(target = ifelse(row_number()==1, target, replace(target, tail(row_number(), N), NA))). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Jage you can use  `replace(target, N > 1 & row_number() %in% tail(row_number(), N), NA)`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`case_when()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html) for a vectorized solution in **`dplyr`**.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(target = case_when(row_number() <= n() - N ~ target))
```

My thanks to [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/u/3732271) for pointing out that `case_when()` defaults to an `NA` of the proper type, so `case_when()` automatically fills the last `N` with `NA`s.

## Update

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73477486) by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/u/3732271) is more performant: when benchmarked at `times = 50` repetitions apiece

```r
library(microbenchmark)

big_df <- tibble(ID = rep(letters, 100000)) %>%
  mutate(target = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(ID)

microbenchmark(
  times = 50,
  Greg = {
    big_df %>%
      mutate(target = case_when(row_number() <= n() - N ~ target))
  },
  akrun = {
    big_df %>%
      mutate(target = replace(target, tail(row_number(), N), NA))
  }
)
```

it is about 35% faster than mine at scale (`2600000` rows):

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
  Greg 82.6337 90.9669 128.93278 96.35760 213.3593 258.8570    50
 akrun 52.4519 55.8314  63.40997 61.43945  64.1082 196.4069    50
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative suggestion:

We could define the top N after using arrange in descending order (with -x), apply our ifelse statement and rearrange:

```
library(dplyr)

N = 2

df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(-x, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(x = ifelse(row_number()== 1:N, NA, x)) %>% 
  arrange(x, .by_group = TRUE)
```

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(2, 4, 6, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 6), id = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```